# Tensor equality

Tags: calculus, summation, tensor-products, tensors

How can I show that

$$
    (\mathbf{T} \otimes \mathbf{T}):\mathbf{P} = tr (\mathbf{T} \cdot \mathbf{P})\mathbf{T}
$$

If I put this into tensor notation, does it get?

Edit per suggestion:
$$
    T_{ij} T_{kl} P_{kl} = tr(T_{lk} P_{km})T_{ij}
$$

Both $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ are 2nd-order symmetric tensors.
The double dot syntax is defined as $\mathbf{T}:\mathbf{P} = T_{ij} P_{ji}$ but since both tensors are symmetric the index order can be exchanged.

How can I prove the equality?

Comment: Hello @KurtG. . I was not able to show this equality based on the post you suggested. Could you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: I can't. Do you have definition of $\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{B}$ when the tensors (like in your case) have different order? Your question lacks details. Don't assume that everyone knows all the notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://unacademy.com/content/upsc/study-material/mathematics/double-dot-product/) the double dot product of two tensors of different order $\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{P}$ is the contraction according to the first tensor’s last two values and the second tensor’s first two values. In case of 4th order $\mathbf{A}$ and 2nd order $\mathbf{P}\,:$
$$
\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{P}=A_{ijkl}\,P_{kl}\,.
$$
Your $\mathbf{A}$ is
$$\mathbf{T}\otimes \mathbf{T}=T_{ij}\,T_{kl}\,.$$
Therefore, as you wrote:
$$(\mathbf{T}\otimes \mathbf{T}):\mathbf{P}=T_{ij}\,T_{kl}\,P_{kl}\,.$$
Since
$$
T_{kl}\,P_{kl}=\mathbf{T}:\mathbf{P}=\operatorname{tr}(T_{ik}P_{kj})
$$
we could write this indeed as
$$
(\mathbf{T}\otimes \mathbf{T}):\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{T}\,(\mathbf{T}:\mathbf{P})=\operatorname{tr}(T_{ik}P_{kj})\,\mathbf{T}\,.
$$
This is the tensor $\mathbf{T}$ times a scalar.
Your notation
$$
T_{ij} T_{kl} P_{kl} = \operatorname{tr}(T_{ik} P_{kj})T_{ij}
$$
for the RHS is slightly incorrect, or at least confusing. If you double all indices it looks like you sum over them and get a scalar. You should better write
$$
T_{ij} T_{kl} P_{kl} = \operatorname{tr}(T_{\color{red}\ell\, k} P_{k\,\color{red}m})\,T_{ij}\,.
$$

Comment: thanks for the note. I will update the post!

Comment: if $\mathbf{P}$ is on the left, does it make a difference ($\mathbf{P}: \left( \mathbf{T} \otimes \mathbf{T}\right)$) [$P_{kl} A_{ij} A_{kl}$]?

Comment: Dear @R.Smith , if we take the definition I linked to word for word then we should have $$\mathbf{P}:\mathbf{A}=P_{kl}\,A_{\color{red}{kl}ij}\,.$$ Can you proceed ?

Comment: yy. Thanks. The end result will be exactly the same

Comment: In that case that is correct.

Comment: One last question [newbish one]: Is $P_{kl} T_{ijkl}$ and  $T_{ijkl} P_{kl}$ the same thing? Only the indices matter right?

Comment: That's right. These expressions are products of ordinary numbers inside a double sum.

Comment: you are the best. I have no one to clarify these things for me, so thanks a lot!